# Content type for multi-part request in soap web services

Tags: java, web-services, soap, content-type, mime

I am writing a Java client to call a SOAP web service.It accepts a file as an attachment so in java, I need to declare the content type as multipart.I am using `apache http` library to write Java client.

I specified it i Java as below

> httppost.setHeader( "Content-Type", "multipart/related" );

but I got the below error

```
Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: MIME boundary parameter not foundmultipart/related
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error. What should be the content type to be specified in Java.

When I specified it as

```
httppost.setHeader( "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8" );
```

Again, i got the below exception

```
 Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamReaderException: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '-' (code 45) in prolog; expected '<'
```

Which one should i go ahead with and how to resolve the respective exception?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to use MTOM+XOP?

The first error is clear: you have no boundary. A multipart is more than simply a content-type, it requires you to mark the different parts with a boundary that has to be declared in the headers and requires linefeeds etc to be in the correct place.

Secondly, you can't just send a file to a SOAP endpoint if that is what you are trying to do, you need to have a soap body in the first part that references the file in the second part.

Comment: I am using apache http library. could you please let me know how to do it

Comment: For effective MTOM+XOP interaction, you need to a know a lot beyond multipart, please read up on it first.

Comment: I am not using MTOM/XOP. There is already a service written. I just need to call it using Java code and apache http library. I am currently stuck with File attaching part. May be I am setting content type incorrectly or anything related to it.